# Can I use listiterator in Java to access elements in random positions?

Tags: java, listiterator

I'm writing code that goes through article records (in database). I load the database in memory and store it in `ListIterator`.

Does anyone know if I can access elements in random positions?

I created this Java example:

```
package com.myjava.listiterator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MyListIterator {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ListIterator<Integer> litr = null;
        li.add(23);
        li.add(98);
        li.add(29);
        li.add(71);
        li.add(5);
        litr=li.listIterator();
        System.out.println("Elements in forward directiton");
        while(litr.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(litr.next());
        }
        System.out.println("Elements in backward directiton");
        while(litr.hasPrevious()){
            System.out.println(litr.previous());
        }

        // How to access litr[3]?
    }
}
```

This code loops through numbers forward and backward. See my last comment. Can I access `litr[3]`?

Comment: Not in the standard JDK, no.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Thanks. Could you post formal answer so I can accept it? An alternative would be good.

Comment: done!........... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> // How to access litr[3]?

No you can't get randomly from an iterator.

From [`ListIterator docs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)

> A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies between the element that would be returned by a call to previous() and the element that would be returned by a call to next().

```
// How to access litr[3]?
```

I can see a possibility here by getting it from list directly  `li.get(3);`

If you don't have a list in hand and only have iterater, first prepare a list

```
List<ObjectType> dupList= new ArrayList<ObjectType>();
while (itr.hasNext())
    dupList.add(itr.next());
```

Alternative if you have to get only one object:

```
ObjectType target =null;
int i = 0;
while(itr.hasNext() && i!=3){
    i++;
    target = itr.next();
}
//access fourth element via target variable.
```

Now pass a random index to this list `(dupList)`

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that my function (that I get to use) only receives ListIterator as argument. I actually dont have access to li.

Comment: @bodacydo Yeah just edited my answer, as per your requirement :)

Comment: for duplicating you have access?

Comment: But why you are building this list? cant you just iterate with iteration counter and fetch value if 'counter=x'?

Comment: @T.G I build a list once and access it, instead of iterating each time.

Comment: @raghavendra What do you mean by access ?

Comment: but question does not point to multiple access. If it does, then dupplication of list is ok, if you need to access one random element, then i'd suggest an my alternative

Comment: what about 2,5,3,7,2 access

Comment: @raghavendra  that `3` must be dynamic, probably input.

Comment: then why op need a loop for that

Answer (score 2):

Your list instance is an ArryaList, simply use it directly.

```
package com.myjava.listiterator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MyListIterator {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        ArrayList<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        li.add(23);
        li.add(98);
        li.add(29);
        li.add(71);
        li.add(5);

        ....

        // How to access litr[3]?
        System.out.println(li.get(3));
    }
}
```

If your method only accept ListIterator and cannot be modified.
Here is a solution if you are not concerned about performance.

```
package com.myjava.listiterator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class MyListIterator {

    public void someMethodOnlyAcceptListIterator(ListIterator<Integer> iterator){
        List<Integer> tmpList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Save all items to the tmpList
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            tmpList.add(litr.next());
        }

        // Access item
        System.out.println(tmpList.get(3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Point here is, OP don't have access to list directly. Only iterator.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yes, that' s why I posted the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use like this `li.get(3)`

you can also do like this but not good.

```
while(litr.hasNext()){
    int curentIndex = litr.nextIndex()-1;
    if(ranIndex > currentIndex) {
         while(litr.hasNext()){
            if(ranIndex  == litr.nextIndex()-1)
               sysout(yourrandomindex);
               after that reset back the list curentIndex 
        }

    }
    // less than code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that my function (that I get to use) only receives `ListIterator` as argument. I actually dont have access to `li`.

Comment: then you have to move the indexs in the literator with some tmp variables

Comment: it is an idea can add a method for this to make it more comfortable

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality in `ListIterator`. `ListIterator`allows for forward and backward iterations.

As for your solution to get `litr[3]`, you can take your `ListIterator`and apply all its elements into an `ArrayList` and do `list.get(3)`.